# Riemannian compact six-dimensional manifolds Ricci-flat

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity, string-theory

Are there Real compact six-dimensional manifolds Real Ricci-flat?

It is known that Calabi-Yau manifolds exist, that is, Complex compact three-dimensional Ricci-flat, but I don't know if Real compact six-dimensional manifolds exist.

If yes, can you provide me with examples or alternatively references?

Can you provide me also with examples of non-compact six-dimensional manifolds Ricci-flat but not Riemann-flat?

Comment: This question seems more suited for MathOverflow

Comment: Isn't a Complex compact 3-dim Ricci flat manifold automatically a real compact 6-dim Ricci flat manifold?

Comment: @Jason DeVito - Thank you for your answer, but if they are the same thngs, why then, for example in string theory, are only the complex version considered?

Comment: Well, I know no physics, but I did not claim they were the same: only that that complex examples form a subset of all the examples.  Perhaps string theorists need the complex structure?  (I am only hazarding a guess - I have no idea.)

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I take any Calabi-Yau manifold and I consider each its complex variable as two real variables (i.e. $z=x+iy$ as $x, y$) I get a real compact 6-dim Ricci flat manifold, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, any Calabi--Yau three-fold is a six-dimensional (real) Ricci flat manifold.  Some examples are discussed by S. Roan and S.-T. Yau in their paper [On Ricci flat 3-fold](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02560039).

Here are two three "easy" examples in the compact case:

1. A six-dimensional torus $T^6$.
2. The Riemannian product $T^2\times K^4$ of a two-dimensional torus and a K3 surface.
3. A Kummer threefold (see Example I in Roan–Yau).

Note that a K3 surface and a Kummer threefold have positive Euler characteristic, and hence, by the Gauss–Bonnet–Chern theorem, are not flat.  Therefore the last two examples are not flat.

It also follows that the Riemannian product $\mathbb{R}^2 \times K^4$ is a noncompact six-dimensional Ricci flat manifold which is not flat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: The last two examples are not flat, but are they Ricci-flat anyway and therefore zero scalar curvature?

Comment: Correct.  Ricci flat implies scalar flat.  Riemann-flat is quite restrictive, as it implies that the universal cover is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much again!